# autotag.vim is loaded but says no tags file

Tags: vim, ctags

I installed autotag.vim by source it in .vimrc. It is listed in `:scriptnames`.

When I tried to jump to tags using `Ctrl+]`, it says

```
No tags file
tag not found:  [function name]
```

If I run `ctag *.c` from command line, then I can search for tags. Any idea why?

I'm on Ubuntu 11.04 x64 and here is a `:version` output

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Mar 24 2011 07:07:02)
Included patches: 1-35
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by buildd@
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+arabic +autocmd -balloon_eval -browse ++builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent -clientserver -clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments +conceal +cryptv +cscope
+cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con +diff +digraphs -dnd -ebcdic +emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search +farsi +file_in_path +find_in_path +float +folding -footer +fork() +gettext
 -hangul_input +iconv +insert_expand +jumplist +keymap +langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent +listcmds +localmap -lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname +mouse -mouseshape +mouse_dec
+mouse_gpm -mouse_jsbterm +mouse_netterm -mouse_sysmouse +mouse_xterm +multi_byte +multi_lang -mzscheme +netbeans_intg -osfiletype +path_extra -perl +persistent_undo +postscript
+printer +profile +python/dyn +python3/dyn +quickfix +reltime +rightleft -ruby +scrollbind +signs +smartindent -sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary
+tag_old_static -tag_any_white -tcl +terminfo +termresponse +textobjects +title -toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo +vreplace +wildignore
+wildmenu +windows +writebackup -X11 -xfontset -xim -xsmp -xterm_clipboard -xterm_save
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -Wall -g -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -Wl,--as-needed -o vim       -lm -lncurses -lselinux   -lacl -lgpm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question.

AutoTag doesn't *create* a `tags` file, it can only update an existing one.

For AutoTag to work reliably you'll need a `tags` file at the same level of the current file or in a parent (like in the main directory of your project).

Comment: I see. I thought it would create tags if they don't exist. Thanks!